# Unable to set usingHistory value of password policy in MAC OSX (10.8.5)

Tags: macos

I am trying set password policy for MAC OSX(10.8.5) using the following commands in terminal

```
sudo pwpolicy -n /Local/Default -setGlobalPolicy "minChars=8 maxChars=32 usingHistory=6 requiresNumeric=1 requiresAlpha=1"
sudo pwpolicy -getGlobalPolicy
maxChars=32 minChars=8 requiresAlpha=1 requiresNumeric=1
```

The problem i am facing is, i am unable to set usingHistory value and it is not even throwing any error.